# Eclipse Websphere can't start the server.- Cannot connect to the server process

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, administrator

I work with Eclipse and WebSphere. My company changes the user's permissions and  I'm not administrator.

Today I want to start the WebSphere server from Eclipse and I get the message

```
Cannot connect to the server process. Make sure the server is already started
```

I created another new server and I get the same message.

From command screen I executed the command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv02\bin>startServer.bat server1
Denied access
```

The whole error trace is

```
ADMU0116I: La información de la herramienta se está anotando en el archivo
           C:\Program Files
           (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\logs\server1\startServer.log
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:267)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WindowsService.getWindowsServiceNameForServer(WindowsService.java:209)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WindowsService.<init>(WindowsService.java:154)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WindowsService.getWindowsServiceInstance(WindowsService.java:139)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.getWindowsServiceIfAvailable(WsServerController.java:161)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.getWindowsServiceIfAvailable(WsServerLauncher.java:157)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:129)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:138)
        ... 5 more
```

[image]

How can I start the webSphere from Eclipse? Do I need administrator permission?

**EDITED**

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
Host Operating System is Windows 8, version 6.2 build 9200
Java version = JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 8 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr15-20131016_170922 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20131016_170922
JIT  - r9_20130920_46510ifx2
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR15_20131016_1337_B170922, Java Compiler = j9jit24, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7
user.install.root = null
Java Home = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\java\\lib;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\classes;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\lib;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\installedChannels;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\lib\\ext;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\web\\help;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\deploytool\\itp\\plugins\\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\\runtime
Classpath = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\lib\startup.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\lib\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\lib\tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\bin;C:\Windows\SysWOW64;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\bin;C:\app\client\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Personal Communications\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Trace Facility\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SCM;.
Current trace specification = *=info:com.ibm.*=all
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[24/11/17 9:15:33:776 CET] 00000000 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: El estado de rastreo de arranque es *=info:com.ibm.*=all.
[24/11/17 9:15:33:792 CET] 00000000 WsServerContr 1   Executing executeUtilityOnWindows with args: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv02\config E101758Node03Cell E101758Node03 server1 
[24/11/17 9:15:33:792 CET] 00000000 WsServerContr 1   Getting WindowsService obj with: server1 and C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv02\config E101758Node03Cell E101758Node03 server1 
[24/11/17 9:15:33:792 CET] 00000000 WindowsServic >  WindowsService for server server1 Entry
                                 <null>
[24/11/17 9:15:33:792 CET] 00000000 WindowsServic >  getWindowsServiceNameForServer server1 Entry
                                 <null>
```

**EDITED NEW TRACE**

I created the new server with the profile was70profile1 and the name is server1

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\bin>startServer.bat server1
Denied Access
ADMU0116I: La información de la herramienta se está anotando en el archivo
           C:\Program Files
           (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\logs\server1\startServer.log
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:267)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WindowsService.getWindowsServiceNameForServer(WindowsService.java:209)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WindowsService.<init>(WindowsService.java:154)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WindowsService.getWindowsServiceInstance(WindowsService.java:139)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.getWindowsServiceIfAvailable(WsServerController.java:161)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.getWindowsServiceIfAvailable(WsServerLauncher.java:157)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:129)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:138)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Is that really the COMPLETE stack trace, with ALL "caused by" sections?

Comment: There's a lot of necessary information missing, such as where the `Denied access` message came from.  This sounds like a problem in the server configuration but debugging it would require access to the server itself, which we cannot do from here.

Comment: The command screen doesn't show more messages. I edited the question with the log. Could the "Denied access " came from the administrator permissions?

Comment: Based on what threw the exception (`com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WindowsService.getWindowsServiceNameForServer`) my guess is that you did not install the server correctly and it is not registered as a Windows Service that can be started by that .bat file.  The code is trying to find the Windows Service name and received `null` from some API call, which it was not prepared to handle.

Comment: I created a new server from Eclipse and I started it from command line and I get the same exception. I edited this new trace

Comment: The server startup is expecting to find a registered Windows Service, which is not there, and whoever wrote the startup code (at IBM) wasn't very thorough thinking about edge cases.  At this point I'd suggest looking in the Websphere bug database.

Comment: When you creating the server, are you adding it as Windows service? I'd strongly suggest not to add it as Win Service. Has your user administrative rights (administrator)?